TypeError: Cannot add property widgetRef, object is not extensible
Using vue/test-utils v1 I was modifying the $refs like this
const wrapper = factory();
wrapper.vm.$refs.widgetRef = {
 actionStep: vi.fn(),
 redraw: vi.fn(),
};

After moving to v2, now its throwing error
TypeError: Cannot add property widgetRef, object is not extensible
How can I mock the widgetRef component in v2?
here is the code for component
// Component.vue
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <child-component ref="widgetRef" />
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {
    Component,
    Ref,
    Vue,
} from 'vue-facing-decorator';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';

@Component({
    components: {
        ChildComponent,
    }
})
export default class WidgetMaximized extends Vue {
    ...
    @Ref()
    readonly widgetRef;
}
</script>


Please, provide code you're testing. Where is widgetRef supposed to be assigned? Generally a ref is supposed to be mocked the natural way, not by accessing $refs directly

added the code.

I'm not sure if the use of Ref() adds some specificity, the decorators aren't well documented. But generally you're supposed to just mock child-component in such test and let vue handle the refs as usual, the $refs tamping was fragile from start

Any way to mock child component with actionStep and redraw methods?

It's like that https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/stubs-shallow-mount.html#Stubbing-a-single-child-component
